# Ajuda por favor - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, netbeans

Estou tentando salvar o valor total de uma venda, porem o seguinte erro esta sendo exibido :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "199,67"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at view.ViewVendas.jButton2ActionPerformed(ViewVendas.java:444)
```

Segue o codigo da linha 444

```
 int codigoVenda = 0, codigoProduto = 0;
        listaModelVendasProdutos = new ArrayList<>();

        modelVendas.setFk_cliente(Integer.parseInt(txtCodCli.getText()));

        try {
            modelVendas.setVen_dataVenda(blDatas.converterDataParaDateUS(new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ViewVendas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        float vltxt = Float.parseFloat(txtValorTotal.getText());
        modelVendas.setVen_valorTotal(vltxt);
        modelVendas.setVen_valor(Float.parseFloat(txtValorTotal.getText()) + valorDesc);
        modelVendas.setVen_desconto(valorDesc);

        codigoVenda = controllerVendas.salvarVendasController(modelVendas);
        if (codigoVenda > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Venda realizada com scesso !", "SUCESSO", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro ao realizar venda !", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        int cont = tblVenCad.getRowCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
            codigoProduto = (int) tblVenCad.getValueAt(i, 0);
            modelVendasProdutos = new ModelVendasProdutos();
            modelProduto = new ModelProdutos();
            modelVendasProdutos.setId_produto(codigoProduto);
            modelVendasProdutos.setId_venda(codigoVenda);
            modelVendasProdutos.setVen_pro_valor((double) tblVenCad.getValueAt(i, 3));
            modelVendasProdutos.setVen_pro_quantidade(Integer.parseInt(tblVenCad.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()));
            //SUBTRAIR DO ESTOQUE
            modelProduto.setId_produto(codigoProduto);
            modelProduto.setPro_estoque(controllerProduto.retornaProdutoController(codigoProduto).getPro_estoque()
                    - Integer.parseInt(tblVenCad.getValueAt(i, 2).toString()));
            listaModelVendasProdutos.add(modelVendasProdutos);
            listaModelProdutos.add(modelProduto);
        }

        if (controllerVendasProdutos.salvarVendasProdutosControllerLista(listaModelVendasProdutos)) {

            controllerProduto.alterarEstoqueProdutoController(listaModelProdutos);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Registrado!", "ATENÇÃO", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            carregarVendas();
            limparFormulario();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Falaha ao criar registro de movimentação !", "ERRO", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A própria exceção já indica o que está acontecendo: tentativa de converter uma String para Float, porém a String não é válida. A String que vc está tentando converter é "199,67" porém o Float não conhece ",". Troque por ".":

```
float vltxt = Float.parseFloat(txtValorTotal.getText().replace(",", "."));
```

```
modelVendas.setVen_valor(Float.parseFloat(txtValorTotal.getText().replace(",", ".")) + valorDesc);
```

No seu código, vi que vc usa bastantes conversões. Tome cuidado.
O cenário ideal e perfeito seria validar essas String antes de tentar converter, aplicando uma regex para saber se ela contém apenas números, por exemplo.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado !!!!!